# Lookup that Use a cell that contains range as lookup value and lookup vector

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

[image]

Sorry, I can't post image here because of restriction. But, I can't find another way to explain my problem.

I have a sheet like that.  And then, I need cell B5 to return a value based on data from table below ID respectively.  In cell A1, I used drop down list that contains IDs.

For example:

> When A1 is 1 then B5 will return value from L5 and C5 will return value from M5.
>
> when A1 is 2 then B5 will return value from L5 and C5 will return value from M5.

So, I create a formula in B5 like this:

> =LOOKUP(A5,LOOKUP($A$1,$E$5:$E$14,$G$5:$G$14),LOOKUP($A$1,$E$5:$E$14,$H$5:$H$14))

And, then I stuck to make G5, H5 and I5 to return a range.

Any solutions?

EDIT:
Sorry, I made a mistake. I've edited the example formula above.

UPDATE DETAILS:

Assuming A1 is 1.  Then the expected formula will be like this:

> =LOOKUP(A5, value of G5 , value of H5)

which G5 for ID 1 should have range K5:K14 and H5 for ID 1 should have range L5:L14 (here's my problem).

if only I can type K5:K14 in G5 and L5:l14 in H5, and both can work as ranges, I think my problem should be solved.

Comment: I'm confused. Your examples for A1 say the same values should be returned in either case.

Comment: And you post, as part of your question, a formula where ***the parentheses aren't even balanced!*** And you say you want `B5` pulling a value from Column `L`, but then you show a formula where `B5` looks at Columns `H` and `I`!

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking at your problem and I think I know what you may be looking for. If you were to type in the ranges in G5:G14, H5:H14 & I5:I14 then you could use the [INDIRECT function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010062413.aspx) to reference them as part of your `VLOOKUP` formula. However, I do not believe that is necessary and `INDIRECT` should be avoided if possible due it being a *volatile* function (among other reasons).

[image]

The formula in B5 is `=IF(ISNUMBER($A$1),VLOOKUP($A5,$H$5:$AT$14,MATCH($A$1,$I$1:$AU$1,0)+B$4,FALSE),"")`. This uses `MATCH` to find which group of name data to bring into B5:B14 from the `VLOOKUP` on column A. Note that I've use *1* and *2* in B4:C4 with a custom number format of *V\alu\e0* to help in the formula.

I've made that sample worksheet available on my OneDrive [here](http://1drv.ms/1vBl5NL) for you to reference and download. Post back with any questions that you may still have and I will try to assist.

[Name1-10.xlsx](http://1drv.ms/1vBl5NL)